# One-to-many relations,select values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables?

```
**object**
object_id|name
1| one
2| two
3| three

**colors**
object_id|color_name
1| red
1| white
2| red
3| white
```

How select all object_id where color_name equals red **AND** white, not red OR white,
like this

```
 `Select object_id 
  From colors 
  WHERE color_name='red' AND color_name='white'`
```

but it crap..

Comment: The query selects rows. A row cannot be red and white at the same time. It only has one colour. Please provide some sample output of what you expect your query to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I want create filter for my site using PHP. When i check for example red and white in multiple checkbox colors, i click seach and filter should show just object one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below using `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select object_id
from colors
where color_name in ('red','white')
group by object_id
having count(distinct color_name) >= 2
```

Then if you want, you can `JOIN` this result set with `object` table like

```
select o.object_id, o.name
from object o join (
    select object_id
    from colors
    where color_name in ('red','white')
    group by object_id
    having count(distinct color_name) >= 2
) tab on o.object_id = tab.object_id
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks for help!
if i want check three colors i should write having count(distinct color_name) >= 3?

Comment: YES and include the 3rd color name in WHERE condition as well